# Convert Stored Function to Select with window-functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, window-functions

I have a function to calculate price value:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[LAWI_DEinkauf](@sArtikelID varchar(36)) 
RETURNS NUMERIC(14, 2) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @menge DECIMAL(16,6)
    DECLARE @tmenge DECIMAL(16,6)
    DECLARE @wert DECIMAL(16,6)
    DECLARE @ekpreis DECIMAL(16,6)
    DECLARE @ekmenge DECIMAL(16,6)

    DECLARE @myposI CURSOR

    SET @ekpreis = 0
    SET @ekmenge = 0
    SET @wert = 0
    SET @menge = 0
    SET @tmenge = 0

    SET @myposI = CURSOR SCROLL FOR
         SELECT einkaufspreis, menge 
         FROM lawi_bewegung 
         WHERE artikelid = @sArtikelID 
         ORDER BY datum, ident;

    OPEN @myposI

    FETCH NEXT FROM @myposI INTO @ekpreis, @ekmenge

    WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN
       SET @tmenge = @tmenge + @ekmenge

       IF @ekpreis <> 0 
           SET @menge = @menge + @ekmenge

       SET @wert = @wert + @ekpreis * @ekmenge

       IF @tmenge = 0 
           SET @wert = 0

       IF @tmenge = 0 
           SET @menge = 0

       FETCH NEXT FROM @myposI INTO @ekpreis, @ekmenge;
    END

    CLOSE @myposI
    DEALLOCATE @myposI

    IF @menge = 0 
        SET @menge = 1

    RETURN @wert / @menge
END
```

I try to convert this stored function to a select with window-functions. Reason is the poor performance of the stored function when this is used in a select with many rows.

Generally this is working like follows:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 
     wert / CASE WHEN menge = 0 THEN 1 ELSE menge END 
 FROM
     (SELECT 
          SUM(menge) OVER (ORDER BY datum, ident) as tmenge, 
          SUM(CASE WHEN einkaufspreis <> 0 THEN menge ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY datum, ident) AS menge,
          SUM(einkaufspreis * menge) OVER (ORDER BY datum, ident) AS wert,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datum, ident) AS rn
      FROM
          lawi_bewegung 
      WHERE
          artikelid = XXXX) a order by rn desc
```

There, XXXX would be the parameter `sArtikelID` (in my case from the outer select).

My problem is the part of the stored function, where the sums are being reset:

```
IF @tmenge = 0 
    SET @wert = 0
IF @tmenge = 0 
    SET @menge = 0
```

How can I include this logic into my select which is using window functions?

Comment: Do you really need the cursor?

Comment: This function should be thrown away. No offense but this is going to suck the performance out of your system. It is a scalar function which is horrible for performance. But then it gets worse with a cursor inside which is even worse for performance. This should be rewritten as an inline table valued function. We need a lot more information though to help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: because it is horrible, i want to change it to windowing-function. this is working except the part with resetting the sum.

Comment: Do you allow negative or zero quantities? Else I'm under the impression that `@tmenge` will never be 0. Can you post some sample data where things are not working in your rewrite?

Comment: Without something to work with this is nearly impossible to answer. Adding some formatting to your code would help immensely. Even your new code is just a wall of text. And be careful using top without an order by.

Comment: @kirchner - menge can be positive and negative (incomings and outgoings)

Comment: Please explain the logic inside the loop of the function. What do the values in menge, wert etc. actually mean. I am not sure if these IF statements are actually needed inside the loop (logically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query seems to solve your problem, but I'm not sure it will perform well. Can you please try it with some data and check the values and perf?

```
WITH step1 AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN SUM(menge) OVER (PARTITION BY artikelid ORDER BY datum, ident) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS reset
    FROM lawi_bewegung
),
step2 AS (
    SELECT *,
        SUM(reset) OVER (PARTITION BY artikelid ORDER BY datum, ident) - reset AS g
    FROM step1
),
step3 AS (
    SELECT artikelid,
        SUM(CASE WHEN einkaufspreis <> 0 THEN menge ELSE 0 END)
            OVER (PARTITION BY artikelid, g ORDER BY datum, ident) AS menge,
        SUM(einkaufspreis * menge)
            OVER (PARTITION BY artikelid, g ORDER BY datum, ident) AS wert,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY artikelid ORDER BY datum, ident) AS rn
    FROM step2
)

SELECT i.artikelid,
    d.*
FROM lawi_inventur i
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1
        CAST(wert / CASE WHEN menge = 0 THEN 1 ELSE menge END AS DECIMAL(14, 2)) AS DEinkauf
    FROM step3 s
    WHERE s.artikelid = i.artikelid
    ORDER BY rn DESC
) d
;
```

The way it works is as follow:

- step 1 will mark the rows where tmenge is 0, which is your reset point;
- step 2 will then do a running sum on the `reset` column, effectively creating a grouping column. Every time tmenge sums to 0, the following rows will have a diferente grouping value;
- step 3 takes advantage of this grouping value and uses it to partition the rows to sum over, using the PARTITION BY option of the OVER clause. It also calculates a ROW_NUMBER() over all the rows, which is then used by the outer query to pick the last row;

It might be easier to understand if you look at the output of the intermediate steps. Just change the last SELECT (last 4 lines) to `SELECT * from step1`, or `SELECT * FROM step2` and so on.

It might help if you have a good index for this query, which would be something like `ON (artikelid, datum, ident) INCLUDE (menge, einkaufspreis)`.

Comment: this works great. One more question: How can I this embed in an other select? I have a table LAWI_Inventur which has a column ArtikelID. Now I want to do a select from LAWI_Inventur and calculate the price for each row of lawi_inventur (with the ArtikelID of the row).

Comment: I edited the answers with the changes needed, but I think this might be a bit too slow. Can you give it a try?